# Dependent properties of model in Angular

Tags: angularjs

In Angular, a key feature is the two-way binding which keeps the model always up to date. However, I have a situation where I have what is essentially a dependent property of a model. My question is about how to implement it. I can insert an expression into the view to display a calculation that depends on elements of the model, but I would like to have that expression assigned as a field in the model, such that other expressions could then use that result with everything updating nicely.

A simple example might have fields **a**, **b**, and **c** in the model, with **c = a * b**. It's possible to put `{{a * b}}` into the view but, I'd rather have a field for **c** such that I could reference **c** in other expressions and simply use `{{c}}` in the view where I need it displayed, with **c** updating whenever **a** or **b** are updated.

I guess you could put a watch on **a** and **b** and recalculate **c**, but it seems like the machinery is already in Angular somewhere to have that done automagically, since it works for expressions in the view. If I don't know the expression ahead of time (and I won't) I'd need to parse the expression for **c** to pull out variables and set up watches on all of them... surely with Angular there is a better way.

Can one do something like put an Angular expression into a model?

I understand that there is a danger here - you could create a self-referential loop, but that would be detectable such that an error could be thrown.

Comment: Controller: `$scope.calculatedVariable = function(){return a*b}` View: `{{ctrl.calculatedVariable()}}`

Answer (score 2):

Knockout has concept of computableObservable but angular has no such different thing. However you can do something like below. It would automatically change the value of c when a has changed. Look at below code snippet.

```js
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.name = 'World';
  $scope.a=5;
  $scope.b=10;
  $scope.c = function(){return $scope.a*$scope.b}
  $scope.changea = function(){$scope.a = 25}
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title>AngularJS Plunker</title>
    <script>document.write('<base href="' + document.location + '" />');</script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.13"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
    <p>Hello {{name}}!</p>
    {{c()}}
    <input type="button" value="change a value to 25" ng-click="changea()" />
    a = {{a}}
  </body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

Kyle and Jenish provide good answers that may be appropriate in many cases, but there is still a subtle difference in that

1. You need to use parens whenever the property is referenced; and
2. There is presumably an efficiency loss in having to calculate the value whenever it is needed as compared to only when its dependencies change.

After searching for 'Computed Property' (thanks Jenish - that's the term I needed) I found that it's possible to eliminate the parens ([thanks to this article](http://angular-tips.com/blog/2014/02/computer-properties-with-javascript-properties/)), but I've not found a solution that saves the value and only updates it when required.

It is possible to add properties to objects in javascript and only define a getter, which is great in itself, but all the greater because it works with the Angular system.

Note that in the snippet below, the 'vars' property is just used to provide a context for math functions and the variables we're exposing to the user for this particular example. Only the `Object.defineProperty(...)` is essential to this general approach.

```js
var app = angular.module('tester', []);

app.controller('VariablesCtrl', function($scope) {

  // Init context with Math for access to functions
  $scope.vars = window.Math;

  // Init variables
  $scope.vars.a = 2;
  $scope.vars.b = 3;
  $scope.vars.c_expr = 'a * b';
  $scope.vars.d_expr = 'pow(c , 2) + 10';

  // Add dependent property to $scope for c and d, based on user input expressions
  Object.defineProperty($scope.vars, 'c', {
    get: function() {
      return $scope.$eval($scope.vars.c_expr, $scope.vars);
    }
  });

  Object.defineProperty($scope.vars, 'd', {
    get: function() {
      return $scope.$eval($scope.vars.d_expr, $scope.vars);
    }
  });

});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" ng-app="tester">

<head>
  <title>Angular Computed Properties</title>
  <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <div ng-controller="VariablesCtrl">
    <p>
      a:
      <input type="number" ng-model="vars.a" />
    </p>
    <p>
      b:
      <input type="number" ng-model="vars.b" />
    </p>
    <p>
      c (an expression):
      <input type="text" ng-model="vars.c_expr" />
    </p>
    <p>
      c: {{vars.c}}
    </p>
    <p>
      d (an expression):
      <input type="text" ng-model="vars.d_expr" />
    </p>
    <p>
      d: {{vars.d}}
    </p>
  </div>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.3.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.3.13/angular.js" data-semver="1.3.13"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is a third way that I believe is true angular way.

You can use $watch on you $scope members to get a callback when variable on your scope changed. In latest angular versions you can watch for group of variables in one command.

So it would be something like

```
$scope.$watch('a', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  $scope.c= newValue + $scope.b;
});
$scope.$watch('b', function(newValue, oldValue) {
  $scope.c= newValue + $scope.a;
});
```

Comment: Is there a way to figure out which variables to watch based on a function or a string expression? Angular seems to be able to do this for view expressions but its not obvious to me how it achieves it. Vire expressions (in double curlies) are updated even when the variables are indirectly dependent such as in Jenish's answer where c() is a function of dependent variables. Once c() is put into an expression in the view, it will be updated when the variables inside that function are updated. How does Angular know that there are variables inside c() that it needs to care about?

Comment: Watch expression is a string with a name of variable in scope ('a' and 'b' in my example), so if you can extract scope variables from your expression then you can make watches in programmatic way. Angular uses $watch internally for updating templates so it doesn't matter if you update it in indirect way. It compares values in scope after any event and calling watches till they stop produce changes to call other watches